# Who "died peacefully" first and when?

Tags: etymology, adverbs, phrase-origin, collocation, origin-unknown

The question came to my mind when I read the recent news of the death of Queen Elizabeth II, first appeared in the official [Twitter](https://twitter.com/RoyalFamily/status/1567928275913121792) account of The Royal Family as:

> The Queen died peacefully at Balmoral this afternoon.

When did the collocation "died peacefully" first appear in written form?

---

*Die peacefully* (often used in past tense as *died*) is a common collocation with the verb *die* and the adverb *peacefully*. *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/peacefully)* dictionary even defines the adverb *peacefully* with the collocation *died peacefully*:

> If you say that someone died peacefully, you mean that they suffered no pain or violence when they died.

*OED* page for the adverb *peacefully* doesn't have any citations with "died peacefully" (or "die peacefully"); although there is a citation with the same semantics from 1864:

> An old man who ended a good and prosperous life peacefully. 
> <sub>1864   M. E. Braddon *Henry Dunbar* xix</sub>

*Died peacefully* appears in two random citations in *OED* (that are not in the pages for *die (v.)* or *peacefully (adv.)*) from 2000's; so it is not possible to find the earliest citation in *OED*. The first written usage of *died peacefully* should be much earlier.

Comment: Google Books has an instance of "died peacefully" from 1606, in [a translation of the History of Justin](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Historie_of_Justine_Containing_a_Nar/c3tnAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1), writing about Ptolemy I Soter. The Latin just says he died ([moritur](https://www.forumromanum.org/literature/justin/texte16.html#2)). I doubt this is the earliest, and would suspect it might occur in French or Latin before English.

Comment: But are you at all interested in knowing about people who died *peaceably*? (It looks like "peacefully" was a pretty rare word at one point in time.)

Comment: @Laurel I didn't know "died peaceably" is used. If it is earlier, it can be mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Wycliffe Bible (1382) contains the expression :

> but thou schalt die in pees,

[Jeremiah 34:5](https://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/24034005)

The Coverdale Bible (1535) has the wording :

> but shalt die in peace

(This is a further translation of the same text as above and can be seen on the same link as above.)

The occasion is the prophet Jeremiah exhorting King Zedekiah of Judah, as to his immediate future.

The original Hebrew wording, written by Jeremiah, son of Hilkiah, would have appeared in about 628 B.C. (see Robert Young's Analytical Concordance).

Comment: I was pretty sure the idea/phrasing was used in the Bible (and possibly similar phrasing in other places too), nice job finding it.

Comment: Apparently I forgot about "died in peace" also which you've proven that it is earlier than "died peacefully". Thank you for finding this info.

Comment: My understanding is that translations of the Bible can be fraught, particularly older European translations of the Hebrew parts, as they largely didn’t have access to the original Hebrew so it was often a translation of the Latin which was a translation of the Greek which was a translation of the Hebrew or something like that. Any sense of whether “will die in peace” or “will die peacefully” is an accurate translation of the original Hebrew here?

Comment: @KRyan The Wycliffe New Testament was from the Vulgate (Latin). The same passage can be seen in other translations (such as the Authorised Version of 1611) as 'die in peace' translated from the Masoretic Hebrew text.

Comment: @KRyan: Checking the link above, the relevant portion of the Hebrew text seems to be the first two words: בשׁלום תמות (_beshalom tamut_, "you [shall] die in peace"). The Hebrew word [שׁלום](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D#Hebrew) (_shalom_) has a somewhat complex range of meanings (including "rest" and "well-being"), but "peace" is indeed the historically conventional translation. It also fits the previous verse, which ends with לא תמות בחרב (_lo tamut becherev_, "you shall not die by the sword").

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that Hebrew doesn't have a suffix corresponding to *-ly*, and regularly uses "in/with <noun>" in situations where English would use "<adjective>ly". So while it's certainly accurate to translate "בשלום" as "in peace" (or "at peace"), I think it would also be reasonable to translate it as "peacefully". (There's no other more-obvious Hebrew translation of "peacefully".)

Answer (score 20):

I searched the MED, and UMich's Middle English and EEBO corpora.

### In peace

I found some hits for "in peace". This one is under the MED's definition of "Peace of heart, soul, or conscience; spiritual peace; harmony between body and soul":

> With þis word he gan deiʒe and is soule al in pes To þe Ioye of heouene wende.
> — [South English Legendary: St. Francis](https://archive.org/details/earlysouthenglis00hors/page/66/mode/2up?q=pes), c1300

This one is even more relevant, though it doesn't use the word "die":

> He sholde in pes endy his lif.
> — South English Legendary: Temporale (Passion of Christ), a1325(c1280)

### Died peaceably

Middle English rarely used "peacefully", instead preferring "peaceably". Here's what I found:

> Kynge Knoght kepte and occupied the same lande..and died peasibly seased tharof.
> — Declaration on Certain Writings Sent out of Scotland, c1475-a1600(a1473)

### Died peacefully

This is the earliest example I found:

> Ptolomy hauing deserued great renowne for the Noblenes of his acts died peacefully
> — [The historie of Iustine](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;didno=A13980.0001.001;g=eebogroup;rgn=works;singlegenre=All;size=25;sort=datea;start=1;subview=detail;type=boolean;view=reslist;xc=1;q1=Peacefully;op2=and;q2=Died), 1606

It may be possible to antedate this. I didn't search in EEBO for other spellings because I'm not sure what other ones may have been in use at the time.

### Variants

While I found "[peacely](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED33177.5)" in the MED, the example there didn't have anything to do with death. I also looked at what other -ly/-li adverbs were used with "died" via a quotation search and didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Great answer that includes the earlier variants I didn't know about.

Comment: Also likely related: "Rest In Peace", often abbreviated as "R.I.P.", which has been carved into gravestones for centuries.  Not sure how to determine what would be the earliest example.  Is there a searchable database for epitaphs like there is for books?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: "R.I.P." stands for the *Latin* phrase "requiescet in pace", which just happens to have the same initials as its conventional English translation.

Comment: @Dan While that may have been its origin, I expect that most modern people consider it an abbreviation for the English phrase, due to this coincidence. Much as they consider "Rx" to be an abbreviation for "prescription" with little knowledge of the original Latin derivation.

Comment: @Dan Well that just shows that this figure of speech predates even the English language, which means we could probably take it back a *lot* further.  Given the biblical references (specifically Old Testament), there's probably an equivalent ancient Hebrew or Aramaic phrase, and it might go back even further than that.

Comment: "R.I.P.", though similar, is a different phrase. One's soul being at peace after death is not the same as having died peacefully. I'd argue the St. Francis example is the former, while the Temporale example is likely the meaning in question.

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether "died peasibly seased tharof" mean "died peaceably while in possession of the land in question" or "died while in peaceable possession of the land in question." EEBO finds the following less ambiguous instance of "died peaceably" in _The enquirie and verdite of the quest panneld of the death of Richard Hune wich was founde hanged in Lolars tower_ (1537): "yet wyll they burne him after he **died peasablie** in his bed / as they dide Wicleffe & Tracie with other / to kepe the symple innocent sowles wich they haue made blynde still to continewe in darknes"